# Google Translate cannot read a .PDF made in LaTeX

Tags: pdf

I have received a .pdf document from a colleague who uses LaTeX (I use Office products and have no knowledge of LaTeX at all). The document however is written in German, a language I speak, but not fluently, so there are parts of the text I need help with. However if I attempt to copy parts and then paste them on e.g. Google translate, the character-spacing between words is deleted, effectively stacking the words one after another. GTranslate cannot then recognise these properly and as a result, it cannot translate. 
Is there a way to go around this? Perhaps, by converting the .pdf to another format (that a Windows user like myself can do)? Also, I've mentioned the problem to my colleague and he couldn't figure out a solution to this, so I'd appreciate any hints as to what I can do (rather than things he could try using LaTeX).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try Adobe Reader, File menu, Save as Text. Also make sure that your colleague has `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and does not use the `ae` package as that breaks copy-paste.

Comment: I think this is of-topic: if you are looking for a solution at the PDF end and not at the LaTeX end then this looks more suitable for SuperUser.

Comment: I would agree that this is off-topic, but why not simply copy-paste the LaTeX in?  (This is assuming you are using Unicode input with XeTeX/LuaLaTeX, or packages like `inputenc` and `fontenc`.)

Comment: You can upload the whole PDF to Google Translate and get a translated HTML View from the PDF which resembles the original layout. However, I get overlapped text whenever there is some text format change in the PDF. Apparently this confuses the translator about the positioning.